# How to ask google password from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-authentication

I'm trying to write extension which will not allow to use chrome window where google user already authetificated.
The reason for this is that computer might be used by other person, and I don't want anyone else to use my google account, and I don't want to sign out each time.

But anyway. I was thinking to use `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` but this will ask current user to approve to use token for my app. Not logon (remember, chrome user already logged in!). So how can I ask user to enter using password, then send it to google, so password is checked?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a code yet. And I don't know what I should write. I need a from with "enter password for currently logged chrome user". So after password entered, it validated by google. But I have no idea how to do that.